# Issue when enabling GCP API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to enable google cloud API using Service usage API with below request code

`request = service.services().enable(name='projects/projectnumber/services/apiname')`

when I try to call API, the above request in a loop as I need multiple API needs to be enabled for a project. response from GCP is different. some APIs are being enabled but for others response is like below

```
"name": "operations/acf.p2-2910031xxxxx-9faxxxxx-xxxx-4381-xxxx-dede881xxxxx",
        "metadata": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Any"
        }
```

here, I'm not sure if the API is enabled or not. Or, what the above response exactly mean.

Can someone help me to understand the response from google.

Comment: The API request returned an "Operations handle". You need to check the status on the handle to determine the result. Since your code did not do that, you can manually look in Cloud Logging to see the status. Tip: Only enable one API at a time and wait for the API to complete before enabling the next API.

Comment: You can explore [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/getting-started#api) on calling API using service usage API.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for the response. Do we have any reference page to identify, or to handle "Operations Handle", or to check how determine the result of the handle?

Comment: Refer to these two links: https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#enabling AND https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/get